# Why do I get IP 10.42.0.1 when plugging in an Ethernet cable?

Tags: network-manager, ethernet, dhcp

For a few months I have the problem on my Ubuntu 14.04 box that **when I plug in my Ethernet cable into, I get the IP `10.42.0.1` assigned instead of getting an IP via DHCP**.

I can fix this problem manually every time by clicking on the network-manager applet icon and clicking on `Auto eth0`, then I get an IP via DHCP.

(Edit: My DHCP server in my router is configured to lease addresses in the range 10.10.10.*, and when I click `Auto eth0`, I get `10.10.10.110`.)

**In the good old days, I could just plug in the cable and `Auto eth0` would become active automatically**. I believe that this stopped working when I used the `Shake internet connection` feature, which I believe uses IPs in the `10.42.0.1` range.

In my network-manager settings, `Auto eth0` is the only configuration available in the `Ethernet` section. In it's configuration, the box `Automatically connect to this network when it is available` is ticked, and its `IPv4 Settings` are set to `Automatic (DHCP)`, `IPv6` settings are set to `Automatic`.

**What can I do about this?**

I'd like to get auto-networking work just as before, when I plug in the cable.

---

Edit: My `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Comment: Please let me know if you need further information, I will provide it.

Comment: What is wrong with `10.42.0.1`? You get this address by dhcp.

Comment: @Pilot6 No, I should not get this address by DHCP; my DHCP server in my router is configured to lease addresses in the 10.10.10.100-200 range, and when I actually click `Auto eth0`, I get the IP `10.10.10.110`. I'll update the question accordingly.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `cat /etc/network/interfaces` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 OK, output attached!

Comment: No more ideas so far. Someone will probably help.

Comment: Check your dhcp servers with `nmap -sU -p 67 --script=dhcp-discover.nse <target>`, Download the `dhcp-discover.nse` script [here](http://nmap.org/svn/scripts/dhcp-discover.nse)

Comment: @A.B. Here's the output: http://lpaste.net/138302

Comment: You get your IP from Google: `Domain Name Server: 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4`

Comment: add this line to your `/etc/network/interfaces/`: 

`iface eth0 inet dhcp`

Comment: @AliRezaMosajjal: What's the idea behind that? I'd rather keep exactly the default Ubuntu `/etc/network/interfaces` file, where automatic DHCP is managed by network-manager. On all my other machines, the default `interfaces` file that comes with Ubuntu (containing loopback only) works perfectly fine without this problem.

Comment: this line just tells the system to set the IP address automatically for eth0. I suppose you can look for alternative solutions if you want but this'll quickly solve your problem IMO

Comment: @AliRezaMosajjal: That doesn't seem to work: When I add that line and boot up, my `eth0` has no IP; the bigger problem with it though is that when you start managing an interface with `interfaces`, then in network-manager/nm-applet, it says `device not managed`.

Comment: @nh2: yes if it's managed by the configuration file it will not work with interfaces, but eth0 should have an IP address. check your DHCP logs and see the packets. Maybe the problem is there

Answer (score 1):

The solution should be as simple as editing your wired connection into Network Manager, then select the tab "IPv4 Settings" and then change the method, from "Shared to other computers" to "Automatic (DHCP)"

Answer (score 1):

It is simply because such IP range [value is hard-coded into the NetworkManager](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1098362).